# Is there a way to take convert a char array to a numeric value past a 4 byte value?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, variable-types

For example I have:

```
Dir[j].FileSize = buffer1[0] << 24| buffer1[1] << 16| buffer1[2] << 8| buffer1[3]
```

which gives me the correct value for `0x6400` which is `25600` but `0xC800` doesnt become `51200` but `-14336` instead. I really like this bitshift method because it makes sense to me but if you know another way of converting it that would be good too :)

Comment: what is the type of buffer ? I think you overflow the max with `buffer1[0] << 24`

Comment: What is the data type of `FileSize`? Please provide a [mre] that contains all of the variable declarations instead of just one line of code entirely out of context.

Comment: `FileSize` should be declared as `unsigned int`instead of `int`. But I think there's something wrong elsewhere : 16 bits values (0xc800)  should not overflow in a 32 bits variable. Are you sure about the MSB/LSB file size encoding in buffer ?

Comment: What type is `buffer[]`? If `buffer[2]` contains 0xC8 and is `char`, it will be interpreted as a negative number.

Comment: It ended up being because I had an int instead of an unsigned int. It interpreted it as a negative value when printing it out.

Comment: Assuming `buffer1` is an array of `char`s, you should cast `buffer1[0]` to `unsigned char`: `(unsigned char)buffer1[0]`. Ditto for `buffer1[1]`,  `buffer1[2]`, and  `buffer1[3]`.